# Why is my app Crashing with RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm doing a recycler method in my android studio project but i have a problem.

Everytime i'm trying to `findViewById` my application is crashing.

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

And i don't understand why because i'm creating my view in the good way.

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                     ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carrito, container, false);
    return view;
}
```

And i'm trying to continue with that

```
    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);

        ...

        Log.e("test : ",Integer.toString(R.id.recyclerBuy));
        recyView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerBuy);
/*        recyView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(),RecyclerView.VERTICAL));
        recyView.setAdapter(buyAdapter);
 */
    }
```

But i'm crashing at the line `recyView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerBuy);`. My R.id.recyclerBuy is not empty.

And here is my RecyclerView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".ui.carrito.CarritoFragment">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerBuy"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="550dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="88dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

        ...

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Anyone have a clue why i'm crashing everytime ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because `onAttach()` callback is called before `onCreateView()`.

The easiest way to fix the issue is placing the code where you finding your `RecyclerView` in `onCreateView()`. Something like:

```
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                 ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carrito, container, false);

    recyView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerBuy);
    // here you recyView won't be null

    return view;
}
```

A good article about fragments lifecycle: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/the-android-lifecycle-cheat-sheet-part-iii-fragments-afc87d4f37fd